# Allow us to limit achievements to the current site, please

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, top-bar

It would be nice if we could limit the achievements view to the current site only. The current view list everything globally.

[image: The achievements from the top bar, showing all changes from all sites.]

Now it would be nice if we would have the option (f.e. with tabs) to limit these to the current site, like in this bad mock-up.

[image: A bad mock-up that shows two small tabs on top of the achievements, labeled "Global" and "Current Site".]

The background is that I always used the (old) reputation-dropdown-from-username to determine what was going on with my stuff, on the current site (f.e. editing/updating old answers which suddenly got attention).

Comment: Good idea, I suggest checkbox: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu5Xy.png which will do only client side filtering, no need for server side logic. One tweak, in http://www.stackexchange.com it should be removed. :)

Comment: You could do this with a user script since the data in there, not sure we'd complicate the UI for that use case though.  You have to remember very few users are active on enough sites for this to be a concern.

Comment: @NickCraver: The main StackExchange dropdown menu has specific functionality for people who are on more than one site, though? (it lists all relevant reputations)

Comment: @NickCraver: That's true, if you guys implement it or not is absolutely your choice, but it is something that worked with the old layout and the new one changed that, so you might want to be aware of it and maybe think about it. It would be a nice addition, though, but I won't shed a tear if it's missing (writing a userscript for it would be a nice exercise).

Comment: @NickCraver - That isn't entirely accurate. The server provides n amount of achievements. If a userscript were used, and the user were highly active on one exchange, but not as much on another, the achievements dropdown would show a very minimalistic representation of that exchange. On the other hand, if it were sent from the server, then a more in depth representation would be provided.